# Retrieving element data with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created an element with data "key" attached, with a value of "0".

**Like this:**

```
<div class="element" key="0"></div>
```

And am trying to retrieve the data with JQuery

**Like this**

```
alert($(".element").key);
```

Expecting to have "0" returned, but instead, it's returned as undefined.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `$(".element").attr('key')`

But better use `data-*` attribute and data api for custom attributes like these.

```
<div class="element" data-key="0"></div>
```

and

```
$(".element").data('key');
```

Comment: I'll take your word for the data-* thing, but out of curiosity, what ways will that help me? What areas of scripting will that influence and make my script work with better? In other words, how does data-* help?

Comment: @jt0dd 1- attribute `key` on a `div` is invalid. 2. Using data api you dont have to do a DOM operation by accessing `.attr`, it will be stored in the internal data-cache of the element and accessed from there, even if not using jquery `.data` you can use `dataSet` on the DOM element as well `$(".element")[0].dataset.key` (Not supported in IE10 and below though)

Comment: @jt0dd Another point is that it casts the result of the data attribute based on its value type. for example see this:= http://jsfiddle.net/83sfJ/

Comment: Ahh, I see. That is definitely more efficient, and I have implemented it!

Answer (score 0):

Need to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) - here `key` is an attribute of the `.element` element so you can use `.attr()` to retrieve this information.

```
$(".element").attr('key')
```

Comment: Whoah.. Aren't you the highest ranked member of StackOverflow? :O

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `alert($('.element').attr('key'));`

Answer (score 0):

var keyVal = $( ".element" ).attr( "key" );

Hope this helps.